# Format of markup affecting display

Tags: html, css

Why am I seeing a difference in the way these 2 nav elements are displayed on the screen? As you can see from this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ska9qc0L/), the unformatted nav doesn't correctly wrap when it reaches the end of the div, and instead overflows through the border, while the formatted markup behaves as I would expect. Why the difference when white space in HTML is supposed to be meaningless?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ska9qc0L/)

Without line breaks between links:

```
<a href="/">Link 1</a><a href="/">Link 2</a><a href="/">Link 3</a><a href="/">Link 4</a><a href="/">Link 5</a><a href="/">Link 6</a><a href="/">Link 7</a><a href="/">Link 8</a>                </nav>
```

With line breaks between links:

```
<nav class="service__nav">
    <a href="/">Link 1</a>
    <a href="/">Link 2</a>
    <a href="/">Link 3</a>
    <a href="/">Link 4</a>
    <a href="/">Link 5</a>
    <a href="/">Link 6</a>
    <a href="/">Link 7</a>
    <a href="/">Link 8</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces indicate the end of a word. The unformatted html doesn't wrap because:

1. There are no spaces between  elements, to indicate an end of a word so the browser doesn't break line between them:

   ```
   <a href="/">Link 1</a><a href="/">Link 2</a><a href="/">Link 3</a>
   ```
2. The `<a>` elements have spaces but `no-wrap` tells the browser not to break lines inside them:

   ```
   .service__nav a {
       white-space: nowrap;
   }
   ```

You dont have to format the HTML, just add spaces between `<a>` elements:

```
<nav class="service__nav">
<a href="/">LinkTest One</a> <a href="/">LinkTest Two</a> <a href="/">LinkTest Three</a> <a href="/">LinkTest Four</a> 
</nav>
```

See updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ska9qc0L/1/)

Comment: Got it. Is there a way to prevent the wrap from occurring within the individual links? For example, if "LinkTest Four" hits the edge of the div, I would like to wrap that whole string to the next line instead of inbetween "LinkTest" and "Four"

Comment: Thats exactly the situation in the answer's attached [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ska9qc0L/1/). Notice the `<a>` elements dont wrap inside because they have `nowrap`. The spaces allow the browser to wrap between them and thats what happens there. Look at the first line there for example: It wraps _after_ "LinkTest Three". Now, delete the `no-wrap` in this example and you will see it wraps _inside_ "LinkTest Four". Hope it helps :)